# How to clone a running windows xp installation to a USB HDD which should be bootable

Tags: windows-xp, usb, boot, clone

i want to clone my Windows XP installation to a USB Hard Drive or maybe an usb memory stick
and then i want to boot from that USB device.

The reason for that is, in case of an emergency i still can boot up the system within minutes without much
trouble of restoring it fist from a backup.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Booting Windows of an USB drive is always ugly and messy. You should add another internal hard drive, clone the windows installation to it and then disconnect the power and data connectors until you need to boot from it.

Comment: What openfkg said.  Now, if this was Windows 7, it might be smart enough to change drive controllers on the fly attempting to boot from USB, but that's NEVER going to happen with XP.  (And it's a bad idea anyway)

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: Creating identical 1:1 copies of tricky disks and other media. HDClone Professional cloning (S)ATA/USB/SCSI/Firewire media with up to 5.4 GB/min. For data rescue, backup, logic restore, bulk installations and many more...

HDClone copies the complete contents of tricky disks and other IDE/ATA, SATA/eSATA, SCSI, USB, and Firewire media on a corporal level. This allows to create even backups or copies of complete operating logic installations smoothly. Inside combination with the special 'SafeRescue' mode of HDClone, this practice is furthermore exact pro rescuing data in justification of defective tricky disks. Furthermore, HDClone facility self-determining of partition describe, gather in a line logic and operating logic (i.E. It facility with FAT, FAT32, NTFS, and that.). Thus, it furthermore facility with proprietary data formats which may possibly not be accessed otherwise. Besides photocopying complete drives, it is furthermore doable to apply it to particular partitions single.